# extracting subset of data based on whether a transaction contains at least a part of the time range in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time, dplyr, intervals

I have a data frame **df** that contains different transactions. Each transaction has a start date and an end date. The two variables for this are **start_time** and **end_time**. They are of the class *POSIXct*.
An example of how they look are as follows "2018-05-23 23:40:00" "2018-06-24 00:10:00".
There are about 13000 transactions in **df** and I want to extract all transactions that contain at least a bit of the specified time interval if not all. The time interval or range is 20:00:00 - 8:00:00 so basically 8 P.M =< interval < 8 A.M.

I am trying to use **dplyr** and the function `filter()` to do this however my problem is I am not sure how to write the boolean expression. What I have written in code so far is this:

`df %>% filter(hour(start_time) >= 20 | hour(start_time) < 8 |hour(end_time) >= 20 | hour(end_time) < 8  )`

I thought maybe this would get all transactions that contain at least a part of that interval but then I thought about transactions that maybe start and end outside of that interval but their duration is so long that it contains those hours from the interval. I thought maybe of adding `| duration > 12` because any start time that has a duration longer than 12 hours will contain a part of that time interval. However, I feel like this code is unnecessarily long and there must be a simpler way but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start with a sample data frame, since a sample `df` isn't given in the question:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(69)
dates <- as.POSIXct("2020-04-01") + days(sample(30, 10, TRUE))
start_time <- dates + seconds(sample(86400, 10, TRUE))
end_time  <- start_time + seconds(sample(50000, 10, TRUE))
df <- data.frame(Transaction = LETTERS[1:10], start_time, end_time)

df
#>    Transaction          start_time            end_time
#> 1            A 2020-04-18 16:51:03 2020-04-19 00:05:54
#> 2            B 2020-04-28 21:32:10 2020-04-29 06:18:06
#> 3            C 2020-04-03 02:12:52 2020-04-03 06:11:20
#> 4            D 2020-04-17 19:15:43 2020-04-17 21:01:52
#> 5            E 2020-04-09 11:36:19 2020-04-09 19:01:14
#> 6            F 2020-04-14 20:51:25 2020-04-15 06:08:10
#> 7            G 2020-04-08 12:01:55 2020-04-09 01:45:53
#> 8            H 2020-04-16 01:43:38 2020-04-16 04:22:39
#> 9            I 2020-04-08 23:11:51 2020-04-09 09:04:26
#> 10           J 2020-04-07 12:28:08 2020-04-07 12:55:42
```

We can enumerate the possibilities for a match as follows:

1. Any start time before 08:00 or after 20:00
2. Any stop time before 08:00 or after 20:00
3. The stop and start times are on different dates.

Using a little modular math, we can write this as:

```r
df %>% filter((hour(start_time) + 12) %% 20 > 11 | 
              (hour(end_time) + 12) %% 20 > 11 | 
              date(start_time) != date(end_time))
#>   Transaction          start_time            end_time
#> 1           A 2020-04-18 16:51:03 2020-04-19 00:05:54
#> 2           B 2020-04-28 21:32:10 2020-04-29 06:18:06
#> 3           C 2020-04-03 02:12:52 2020-04-03 06:11:20
#> 4           D 2020-04-17 19:15:43 2020-04-17 21:01:52
#> 5           F 2020-04-14 20:51:25 2020-04-15 06:08:10
#> 6           G 2020-04-08 12:01:55 2020-04-09 01:45:53
#> 7           H 2020-04-16 01:43:38 2020-04-16 04:22:39
#> 8           I 2020-04-08 23:11:51 2020-04-09 09:04:26
```

You can check that all the times are at least partly within the given range, and that the two removed rows are not.